# Ошибка laravel Undefined index: id

Tags: laravel

> ErrorException in PagesEditController.php line 35:
>   Undefined index: id

Контроллер:

```
$validator = Validator::make($input,[

    'name'=>'required|max:255',
    'alias' => 'required|max:255|unique:pages,alias,'.$input['id'],
    'text' => 'required'

]);
```

Comment: У вас нет такого элемента в массиве, с таким ключом

Comment: А что вы собственно хотите сделать ?

Comment: @Shadow33 он видимо хотел поле на уникальность проверить в столбце )

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка возникает при попытке удалить страницу в админке.
Станица как бы должна удаляться, но не удаляется а код работает дальше до строки с id (это уже код редактирования страницы) и выдает ошибку. Само редактирование страницы работает.

Вот более полная часть кода:

```
if($request->isMethod('delete')) {
        $page->delete();
        return redirect('admin')->with('status','Страница удалена');
    }


    if($request->isMethod('post')) {


        $input = $request->except('_token');

        $validator = Validator::make($input,[

            'name'=>'required|max:255',
            'alias' => 'required|max:255|unique:pages,alias,'.$input['id'],
            'text' => 'required'

        ]);
```